# How to store the value from the list to a variable in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

[image]I am new to selenium webdriver. I want to extract the value from the Ul class and store it in a variable but i am not able to do so

this is what i tried
WebElement testuser = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".box  ul.form li:nth-child(4)"));

div class="box"
        ul class="form"

User Type

School Administrator

```
        <li><h4>First Name</h4></li>
        <li>Faleata</li>
```

Its saying unable to locate the elements

Comment: Do you want to get values of `User Type` and `First Name` from ui?

Comment: Only the first name value and store it to a variable. I basically want to get to know how do we do from checking the entire list. I check the values in the list completely and finally extract it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle dynamic element use `WebDriverWait` and try the below `xpath`.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='box']/ul[@class='form']//li[./h4[text()='First Name']]/following::li[1]")));
System.out.println(element.getText());
```

Comment: thank you for help, may i know why the a "." is been used before the h4.

Comment: It finds the child h4 inside li whose text value First Name.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do if its like i have to pick from the List and verify. like using List<Webelement> , fetch all the values  and store it in list and then verify to get the text.

Comment: what value you wanted to verify?

Comment: @paulbaboo : I will suggest better to post a new question with new requirements.This community is not only for to help yourselves but it should help future readers.I hope understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this bellow code

```
WebDriverWait waitElmt = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
WebElement element = waitElmt.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//ul[@class='form']//li)[4]")));
String getText = element.getText();
System.out.println(getText);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following given below code snippet

```
WebDriverWait waitforelement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

string elementpath = "//div[@class='box']//child::ul[@class='form']//child::li[4]";

WebElement firstname = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
(By.xpath(elementpath)));

System.out.println(firstname.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the [selenium.support](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.Support) package, there's a lot of nice capabilities

it just this easy:

```
    IWebElement selectWebElement = filterColumns.FindElement(By.TagName("select"));
    SelectElement select = new SelectElement(selectWebElement);
    IList<IWebElement> optionsWebElements = select.Options;
```

and there's a lot more

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
WebElement element = Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeVisible(By.xpath("(//ul[contains(text(),'First Name'])));
String getText = element.getText();
System.out.println("Extracted value is: "+getText);

You can add for loop if you have a common element.